# Adverb clause: his delight evident

Tags: grammar, adverbs, clauses

I recently have come across a clause, *his delight evident*, reading a novel. Which I have found tricky to understand. I have been able to get to the meaning yet not to the structure it possesses.

Here are some improvised sentences I've just made.

- He ran over to me, his delight evident, and hugged me already.
- "Absolutely," said the man, his delight evident.

Could you please explain how the clause works?

Thanks.

Comment: What's with the ***already*** in the first example? It reads like a caricature of a Jewish speech pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an example of a [reduced] absolute phrase.

The following from [grammar.ccc.com](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/phrases.htm):

> ABSOLUTE PHRASE
>
> Usually (but not always, as we shall see), an
>   absolute phrase (also  called a nominative absolute) is a group of
>   words consisting of a noun  or pronoun and a participle as well as any
>   related modifiers. Absolute  phrases do not directly connect to or
>   modify any specific word in the  rest of the sentence; instead, they
>   modify the entire sentence, adding  information. They are always
>   treated as parenthetical elements and are  set off from the rest of
>   the sentence with a comma or a pair of commas  (sometimes by a dash or
>   pair of dashes). Notice that absolute phrases  contain a subject
>   (which is often modified by a participle), but not a  true finite
>   verb.
>
> *Their reputation as winners secured by victory, the New York
>   Liberty  charged into the semifinals.*
>
> *The season nearly finished, Rebecca Lobo and Sophie Witherspoon 
>   emerged as true leaders.*
>
> *The two superstars signed autographs into the night, their faces  beaming 
>   happily.*
>
> When the participle of an absolute phrase is a form of to be, such as 
>   being or having been, the participle is often left out but understood.
>
> *The season [being] over, they were mobbed by fans in Times Square.*
>
> *[Having been] Stars all their adult lives, they seemed used to the  attention.*

Answer (score 2):

It is a participle phrase, with the verb implied. The sentence could be written

> He ran over to me, his delight [*being*] evident, and hugged me already.

The phrase is used adjectivally to modify the pronoun *He*.

It is very common to omit the participle *being* when the phrase includes both a noun (such as *delight*) and predicate adjective (such as *evident*).

Comment: It is **not** a participle phrase. _Recognize a participle phrase when you see one.
A participle phrase will **begin** with a present or past participle._ [bolding mine] {From [this article](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm)}.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What is it?

Comment: It's an absolute phrase (with, as you say, 'being' deleted).